# How to annotate sub-documents in Doctrine MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm, doctrine-mongodb

I want to implement php classes that should model the following :
(Symfony,DoctrineMongoDBBundle)

```
Notification Collection { from { id , fname } , to , sentDate }

Member Collection { id , fname , lname , email , phone , regDate , ... }
```

And i want tell to ODM : "from field is an object that holds only 2 values ,id of the sender and his fname"

What annotation i must use? Should i define another class like from.php ? Or i can create two classes as the following:

```
/*
 *@Document
 */
class Notification {
/*
 *@Id
 */
protected $id;

/*
 *@EmbedOne(targetDocument="Member")
 */
protected $from;

/*
 *@ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Member")
 */
protected $to;

/*
 *@Date
 */
protected $sentDate;
}


/*
 *@Document
 */
class Member {
/*
 *@Id
 */
protected $id;

/*
 *@String
 */
protected $fname;

/*
 *@String
 */
protected $lname;

/*
 *@String
 */
protected $email;

.
.
.
}
```

If it's correct,in my controller how can i control "from" field to hold only id and fname from a Member object?
suppose this:

```
$senderUser;
$newNotification = new Notification();
$newNotification->setFrom($senderUser);
```

Then $newNotification->from set to a Member object that hold all info about a Member.But i want only id and fname of the sender to persist! (because needs of my project)
Excuse my English grammatical errors.
Thanks for any help...

Comment: you should use references in this case

Comment: Thanks @Pazi. What happened if I use EmbedOne for from field?And when I create an instance of Member for it,I assign only my desired fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on nesting the notification's originating user ID and first name in a `from` field, then you will need an [Embed One](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#embedone) relationship to a From document, which in turn has the following fields:

- `id`: this should be a [Reference One](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#referenceone) relationship to a Member document. I would suggest using the `simple` option for the reference, so that you only store the Member's ID value, rather than a [DBRef](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#dbrefs) object.
- `fname`: this should be a string field. ODM has no facility for keeping it up-to-date with the referenced Member document, so you will need to ensure that on your own.

Personally, the Notification document seems small enough that I would simply create `fromMember` and `fromMemberFirstName` fields directly on Notification. Then, you could add some logic in the `setFromMember()` method that also sets the `fromMemberFirstName` field from the passed Member argument.

If you want to take things a step further, you could explore using [events](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/events.html) to monitor Member objects for changed `fname` fields and issue queries to update Notification documents, but that's a separate conversation.